# ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "LeadFacilityAssign.assigned_facilities" must be a "Facility" instance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've been trying to create an api endpoint to update my "lead" objects and add a list of facilities to them when sending a put request (each time a different amount of facilities). The lead objects already exist inside the database so do the facility objects. Since i need a date and time associated to each facility when they are being added to a lead i created the "LeadFacilityAssign" class.
Since i wasn't able to get it to work i tried to do it just with a post request for now, during the lead creation process. I was told that i need to use bulk_create if i need to add more than one facility this way. I couldn't find anything on bulk_create inside the drf documentation so i decided to do this for now just with one facility and improve my code from there one issue at a time since i'm new to drf.

Does anyone know what is causing this error? I tried a few different things but nothing worked so far.

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "LeadFacilityAssign.assigned_facilities" must be a "Facility" instance.
```

serializers.py

```
class LeadUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    assigned_facilities = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    datetime = serializers.DateTimeField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = (
            "id",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "assigned_facilities",
            "datetime",
        )
        read_only_fields = ("id", "created_at", "agent", "is_owner")

    def get_is_owner(self, obj):
        user = self.context["request"].user
        return obj.agent == user
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        assigned_facilities = validated_data.pop("assigned_facilities")
        datetime = validated_data.pop("datetime")
        instance = Lead.objects.create(**validated_data)
        instance.leadfacility.create(assigned_facilities=assigned_facilities,datetime=datetime)
        print(instance)
        return instance
```

models.py

```
class Facility(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Lead(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

class LeadFacilityAssign(models.Model):
    assigned_facilities = models.ForeignKey(Facility, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='leadfacility')
    lead = models.ForeignKey(Lead, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='leadfacility')
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
```

views.py

```
class LeadCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsLeadOwner]
    serializer_class = LeadUpdateSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(agent=self.request.user)

class LeadUpdateView(UpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsLeadOwner]
    serializer_class = LeadUpdateSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Lead.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add `Integer` value into `FK field`.

You have 2 options. You can change the serializer field.

```py
assigned_facilities = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Facility.objects.all(), required=True, write_only=True)
```

OR

```py
    assigned_facilities = serializers.IntegerField(required=True, write_only=True)
instance.leadfacility.create(assigned_facilities_id=assigned_facilities,datetime=datetime)
```

I would rather use 1 option.

Comment: Both return this: AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `assigned_facilities` on serializer `LeadUpdateSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Lead` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Lead' object has no attribute 'assigned_facilities'.

Comment: Add `write_only=True`, I updated my answer

Comment: Love your solution @UtkucanBıyıklı really easy way to handle fields related in custom serializers.

Comment: I was not aware of that approach!

Answer (score 1):

Another potential solution you can apply:

```
class LeadUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    assigned_facilities = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    datetime = serializers.DateTimeField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = (
            "id",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "assigned_facilities",
            "datetime",
        )
        read_only_fields = ("id", "created_at", "agent", "is_owner")
   
    def validate_assigned_facility(self, facility_pk)->:
        assigned_facility = Facility.objects.filter(pk=facility_pk).first()
        if assigned_facility:
            return assigned_facility
        raise ValidationError('Facility not found, provide a valid pk')

    def get_is_owner(self, obj):
        user = self.context["request"].user
        return obj.agent == user
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        assigned_facilities = validated_data.pop("assigned_facilities")
        datetime = validated_data.pop("datetime")
        instance = Lead.objects.create(**validated_data)
        instance.leadfacility.create(assigned_facilities=assigned_facilities,datetime=datetime)
        print(instance)
        return instance
```

This solution is kind of big but is so flexible 'cause give you the opportunity to add more business logic around the input and the expected data in the model or datasource.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It looks very good and makes a lot of sense. My  issue with this solution is though that it only seems to work to send one facility with one date which is why i moved to a json field based solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74303934/django-db-utils-integrityerror-null-value-in-column-of-relation-violates-not-nu