# How to loop through a jsonfield serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've been trying to loop through the incoming data from a json serializer for a couple of weeks now. Tried a few different approaches, but i can't seem to loop through the json and return a list with all facility_id's for example. Ultimately i want to create one leadfacility object for each json item using it's facility_id and it's datetime. But I can't even seem to access the facility_id when using a for loop.
The facilities that are being assigned are already inside the database.

Does anyone know what I'm missing here? How can i loop though "assigned_facilities"? The only thing I am able to return is the entire json data all at once with print(). Or is my json data structured in the wrong way?

```
class LeadUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    assigned_facilities = serializers.JSONField(required=False, allow_null=True, write_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        
        assigned_facilities = validated_data.pop("assigned_facilities")
        instance = Lead.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for item in assigned_facilities:
            instance.leadfacility.create(assigned_facilities_id=assigned_facilities.get('facility_id'), datetime=assigned_facilities.get('datetime'))
            
        return instance
```

json

```
{
    "assigned_facilities": [{
            "facility_id": "1",
            "datetime": "2018-12-19 09:26:03.478039"
        },
        {
            "facility_id": "1",
            "datetime": "2019-12-19 08:26:03.478039"
        }
    ]
}
```

models.py

```
class LeadFacilityAssign(models.Model):
    assigned_facilities = models.ForeignKey(Facility, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='leadfacility')
    lead = models.ForeignKey(Lead, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='leadfacility')
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

class Facility(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Lead(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
```

Comment: What is the relationship between `Lead` and "leadfacility" models?

Comment: @gripep I added it above so you can check it out

Comment: Can you also share the `Lead` and `Facility` models?

Comment: @gripep Added them above just now

Comment: I still need more context here. Should the facilities exist before assigning them to a lead? Please also add it to your description so everyone can get also this piece of context :)

Comment: Yes. The facilities that are being assigned are already inside the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a different, arguably better approach. Instead of `JSONField` use a nested model serializer.

```
class AssignedFacilitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fields = ('assigned_facilities_id', 'datetime')
    model = Facility

class LeadUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    assigned_facilities = AssignedFacilitySerializer(many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        assigned_facilities = validated_data.pop("assigned_facilities")
        instance = Lead.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for item in assigned_facilities:
            instance.leadfacility.create(**item)
            
        return instance
```

You haven't posted your `Facility` model, so there may be some improperly named fields, maybe the `related_name` too (`leadfacility`).

Comment: I was thinking about something like this aswell, but i'm trying to add more than one facility id plus datetime to each lead. I don't see how i would add multiple ones with this approach. I added all the models above just now.

Comment: I don't understand. `AssignedFacilitySerializer` would give you a collection, because it has `many=True`. You then add all of them in the `for` loop.

Comment: I changed the model to the "LeadFacilityAssign" model since thats where the datetime and the facility id is. I assume that is correct. This seems to be working. Seems like i just have to figure out what the dictonary needs to look like that i'm sending to the AssignedFaciltiySerializer.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing :

```
for item in assigned_facilities:
        instance.leadfacility.create(assigned_facilities_id=assigned_facilities.get('facility_id'), datetime=assigned_facilities.get('datetime'))
```

but not using item anywhere.

Comment: What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in assigned_facilities:
    instance.leadfacility.create(assigned_facilities_id=item['facility_id'], datetime=item['datetime'])
```

Comment: That will return the following error: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Answer (score 0):

When you use `pop()` it gets and then deletes the data. That is why u are unable to process it in for loop.
Use `get()` instead of `pop()`, and ur problem will be solved.
Change this line:

```
assigned_facilities = validated_data.pop("assigned_facilities")
```

to:

```
assigned_facilities = validated_data.get("assigned_facilities")
```

Comment: This will return: TypeError: Lead() got an unexpected keyword argument 'assigned_facilities'

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues in both your models and how you add facilities to a lead in your loop.

Please take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships and edit your models accordingly.

TL;DR

You can then put extra fields on the intermediate model.
This is `LeadFacilityAssign` in your case.

The intermediate model is associated with the `ManyToManyField` using the `through` argument to point to the model that will act as an intermediary.
You are missing this part. Make sure to add a `ManyToManyField` to `Leads`.

If you keep reading the docs, you will also find that you can use `add()`, `create()`, or `set()` to create relationships between `Lead` and `Facility` using the through model.

You mentioned facilities already exist, so `create()` is the wrong method.
Please use `add()` or `set()` according to your use case and pre-fetch those facilities using their id.